# How to determine if an app was launched via open as root on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, process, sudo

In OS X, how can I determine if an app launched via the open command was launched with elevated permissions?

I tried as an example `sudo open http://www.google.com/`, but Activity Monitor doesn't seem to display information showing that the Safari process is running as root.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There's a reason browsers get sandboxed (special *lower* permissions), running them as root is not usually something you'd want...

Comment: My posted got edited. I don't need a browser to be opened with root permissions. I need a way to determine if an `open` command was launched with root permissions in OS X.

Comment: And why do you need a way to know if an `open` command was launched with root permissions? What are you *really* trying to do? It's just that in most cases, asking your *actual* question will give you better answers. That's what I was trying to point out.

Comment: We need to verify that the software is launching open with the proper permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Adding a second answer for the clarified question)

When you you used `sudo open http://google.com`, the the system ran `open`
as root, but `open` is really just a client for [MacOS LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-SW15), 
which is still running as the logged-in user.

In fact Activity Monitor is showing you that the Safari instance opened
by `sudo open http:/google.com` is *not* running as root, as the "User"
column is showing your username, not `root`.

You can, however, just invoke Safari directly on the command line with
sudo, by-passing Launch Services:

```
$ sudo /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari http://google.com
```

Now in Activity Monitor, you can confirm that it's running as `root`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for: "The system ran open as root, but open is just a client for Mac OS LaunchServices which is still running as the logged in user."

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "running as root". Note that just because you're running as root, doesn't mean you're running at highest priority; nor does using the `sudo` command necessarily mean the process is running as root.

But those two caveats aside, try this from a Terminal command prompt:

```
$ ps aux | grep ^root
```

To filter the process list for those running as root.
Or even (depending on your version of Mac OS):

```
$ ps -u root
```

Comment: I think the problem might be that when I launch `sudo -u root open http://www.google.com/`, the browser is not opened under the root user and I'm not sure why not.

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri You might just want to ask for your real problem instead of your attempted solution. Why not actually ask how to … do whatever it is that you want? Why do you need a browser to be opened with root permissions? This will most likely get you better answers and will actually solve your *real* problem.

Comment: I never posted an attempted solution so I'm not sure what you are talking about. I don't want to run a browser as root. I want to know why the command was not working as expected.

Comment: Feel free to delete this answer if it's become irrelevant. By the way: You can always edit your answer – even if it radically changes its content.

Answer (score 0):

To see a log of the processess that have been run using `sudo` you can `grep` the system.log:

```
$ grep sudo /var/log/system.log
```

You can also use the Console application.  Select "system.log" from the log list and type "sudo" in the search bar.